# Strange spacing behaviour in HStack embedded in a VStack

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have an `HStack` to layout a `TextField` and a `Button` next to each other. I embedded it in a `VStack` to show a line below. I noticed that the vertical spacing in this case is not the same as the standard `VStack` layout. See details in the following screenshot. Can someone please help me understand this behaviour and how am I supposed to fix it?

[image: screenshot]

Edit: Code below

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var username: String = ""
    @State private var password: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 8) {
        
            VStack {
                TextField("Username", text: $username)
                    .background(Color.red.opacity(0.5))
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.blue)
                    .frame(height: 1)
            }
            .background(Color.blue.opacity(0.5))
    
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    SecureField("Password", text: $password)
                        .background(Color.blue.opacity(0.5))
                    Button(action: { }, label: { Image(systemName: "eye")     })
                }
                .background(Color.red.opacity(0.5))
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.blue)
                    .frame(height: 1)
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is about your coding way, here a working way:

---

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var username: String = ""
    @State private var password: String = ""

    var body: some View {

        VStack(spacing: 8) {
        
            VStack {
                
                TextField("Username", text: $username)
                    .background(Color.red.opacity(0.5))

                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.blue)
                    .frame(height: 1)

            }
            .background(Color.blue.opacity(0.5))
            
            VStack {

                SecureField("Password", text: $password)
                    .background(Color.blue.opacity(0.5))
                    .overlay(Button(action: { }, label: { Image(systemName: "eye") }), alignment: .trailing)
 
                
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.blue)
                    .frame(height: 1)
                
            }
            .background(Color.red.opacity(0.5))
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

---

**Update:**

```
 struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var username: String = ""
    @State private var password: String = ""

    var body: some View {

        VStack(spacing: 8) {
        
            VStack {
                
                TextField("Username", text: $username)
                    .background(Color.red.opacity(0.5))
                    .frame(height: 20)

                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.blue)
                    .frame(height: 1)

            }
            .background(Color.blue.opacity(0.5))
            
            VStack {
                
                HStack {
                    
                    SecureField("Password", text: $password)
                        .background(Color.blue.opacity(0.5))

                    Button(action: { }, label: { Image(systemName: "eye").resizable().scaledToFit().frame(height: 20) })
  
                }

                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.blue)
                    .frame(height: 1)
                
            }
            .background(Color.red.opacity(0.5))
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think so. I specially added the background color on the two textfields and it appears to me that the height is the same.

Comment: @Dree: I update the code plz try again! I think there was not frame issue, the issue was your coding way.

Comment: Adding the button as overlay of the textfield is not a great idea, because this way very long text would appear under the button.

Comment: @Dree: then use my second update, it does what you want

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the default spacing in VStack is may vary depending on the views inside.

It behaves differently if you have `TextField` and `Rectangle` and differently if it's `HStack` and `Rectangle`.

I suggest you add an explicit spacing:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var username: String = ""
    @State private var password: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 8) {
            VStack(spacing: 3) { // add here
                TextField("Username", text: $username)
                    .background(Color.red.opacity(0.5))
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.blue)
                    .frame(height: 1)
            }
            .background(Color.blue.opacity(0.5))

            VStack(spacing: 3) { // add here
                HStack {
                    SecureField("Password", text: $password)
                        .background(Color.blue.opacity(0.5))
                    Button(action: {}, label: { Image(systemName: "eye") })
                }
                .background(Color.red.opacity(0.5))
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.blue)
                    .frame(height: 1)
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```